# Why my script work half?

Tags: php

I’m using this code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$selStat = "SELECT obqva_id, COUNT(*) as broqch FROM statist WHERE date='$date'  GROUP BY obqva_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 8 ";
$queryStat = mysqli_query($conn, $selStat);

while ($rowStat = mysqli_fetch_array($queryStat)) {
    $count = $rowStat['broqch'];
    $id = $rowStat['obqva_id'];

    echo $id.' - '.$count.'<br>';

    $selBest = "SELECT * FROM view WHERE id='$id' GROUP BY $count ";
    $queryBest = mysqli_query($conn, $selBest);
    **$rowView = mysqli_fetch_array($queryBest);** this problem !

    $selImage = "SELECT * FROM  upload WHERE obqva_id='$id'";
    $queryImage = mysqli_query($conn, $selImage);
    $rowImage = mysqli_fetch_array($queryImage);
    ?>
```

[image]

Which produces this output:
[image]

First and next result has a problem, three and next have no problem... why?
First number 41 is ID next number total view.

Comment: You're going to need to show more of your code, in particular the part that outputs the content in your image

Comment: So its telling you that the error occurred on line 208, which i think you've marked. But the problem really started two lines up with the select statement which didn't return the type of data you expected; somehow it failed and returned FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the query is not valid, or there was no result.
thats why you get a bool instead of a resource.
you can filter that by putting your mysqli_query function in an IF statement, like this:

```
$selBest = "SELECT * FROM view WHERE id='$id' GROUP BY $count ";
if($queryBest = mysqli_query($conn, $selBest)){
    $rowView = mysqli_fetch_array($queryBest);
}
else{
    $rowView = false;
}
```

That's that, now for the query. You are trying to group the result on a number:
SELECT * FROM view WHERE id='$id' GROUP BY **$count**
Not sure why you want to group, as it seems that you only want to get some info on a specific id. In that case, i would get rid of the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the GROUP BY statement from the query as i suggested?

Comment: I remove GROUP BY and my script is OK, I very thanks !